# Check whether iterator belongs to a list

Tags: c++, stl

Is there any way to check whether a given iterator belongs to a given list in C++?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### The obvious but invalid approach

You can't simply iterate through the list, comparing each iterator value to your "candidate".

The C++03 Standard is vague about the validity of `==` applied to iterators from different containers (Mankarse's comment on Nawaz's answer links http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2948.html#446), some compilers (eg. VC++2005 debug mode) warn if you do so, but despite all that it may actually work reliably depending on your compiler/libraries - check its documentation if you don't care about portability.

The C++11 Standard is very explicit, **you can't compare iterators to different containers**:

> § 24.2.5 The domain of == for forward iterators is that of iterators over the same underlying sequence.

So, the answers to this question that rely on `operator==` are questionable now, and invalid in future.

### An oft-valid approach

What you *can* do is iterate along the list, comparing the address of the elements (i.e. `&*i`) to the address of the object to which your other iterate points.

- Mankarse's comment cautions that this might not work as intended for objects providing their own `operator&`.  You could work around this using [`std::addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof), or for C++03 [boost's version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#addressof)
- Martin's comment mentions that you have to assume the candidate iterator that you're testing list membership for is safely dereferenceable - i.e. not equal to an `end()` iterator on the container from which it came.  As Steve points out - that's a pretty reasonable precondition and shouldn't surprise anyone.

(This is fine for all Standard containers as stored elements never have the same address, but more generally user-defined containers could allow non-equal iterators to address the same value object (e.g. supporting cycles or a "flyweight pattern" style optimisation), in which case this approach would fail.  Still, if you write such a container you're probably in a position to design for safe iterator comparison.)

Implementation:

```
template <class IteratorA, class IteratorB, class IteratorC>
inline bool range_contains(IteratorA from, const IteratorB& end,
                           const IteratorC& candidate)
{
    while (from != end)
        if (&*from++ == &*candidate)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Notes:

- This adopts the Standard library approach of accepting a range of iterator positions to search.
- The types of each iterator are allowed to vary, as there are portability issues, e.g. containers where `begin()` returns an `iterator` but `end()` returns a `const_iterator`.
- Iterators other than `from` are taken by `const` reference, as iterators can sometimes be non-trivial objects (i.e. too large to fit in a register, relatively expensive to copy).  `from` is needed by value as it will be incremented through the range.

Comment: Note that this still will only work for ForwardIterators (and refinements thereof), so care is needed in the general case.

Comment: *... comparing the address of the elements ...* -- Except of course that if the passed iterator happens to point to an `end()` (or the `begin()` of an empty list), dereferencing it is UB again. What a mess! :-)

Comment: @Mankarse: agreed - I can't see this test being meaningful in the context of input or output iterators.

Comment: @Martin: yes... I take that as a precondition... the iterator for which the containers unspecified must be known to address an element of some container...

Comment: Just nitpicking, but this might also not work correctly for types that have overloaded operator&.

Comment: @Tony: and that's a reasonable precondition, I think. The only thing you can validly do with an `end` iterator (of InputIterator category) is compare it with another iterator from the same container using `==` or `!=`. So unless the caller also tells you what container the iterator is from, you have to make some requirement on the iterator to avoid that case.

Comment: @Mankarse: true again... though there's then a fair chance that you'd want it to work on whatever `operator&` returned....  @Steve: I'll add something about the issue to the answer.  Cheers.

Comment: "iterators can sometimes be non-trivial objects" - although note that if so, the standard doesn't care. All the algorithms take iterators by value, whether they strictly need a copy or not.