# C++ iterator of list

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: Check if iterator belongs to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302706/c-check-if-iterator-belongs-to-a-list)

How can I check if an iterator recieved by function belongs to the right list?

```
List<double> doublesList;
List<double> doublesList2;

// Can't mix iterators
ASSERT_THROW(ListExceptions::ElementNotFound, doublesList.remove(doublesList2.begin()));
ASSERT_THROW(ListExceptions::ElementNotFound, doublesList2.insert(5.0, doublesList.begin()));
```

I askes for the  case of my own Linked List and my own Iterator.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is `List`? Do you mean `std::list`?

Comment: That depends on the implementation of your `List`

Answer (score 5):

With standard containers, you can't. The C++ standard library leaves this up to the programmer. Comparison of iterators [invokes UB](http:///questions/6302706/c-check-if-iterator-belongs-to-a-list), in fact.

With homegrown containers, you can insert information into the iterators so that they remember which container they belong to; that makes the iterators heavier, of course, so it's often only sensible in debug mode.

Comment: -1 your answer is for std::list not whatever this guy is asking about which is obviously not STL ("ListExceptions" and "List<>")

Comment: @SoapBox: realized that, although too late.