# Share iterators the same iterable?

Tags: c++, iterator

I'd like to find out if two itertors share the same iterable. Like here:

```
typedef std::list<int> IntList;

IntList l;
IntList j;

// fill the lists

IntList::iterator start = l.begin();
IntList::iterator end = j.end();

std::cout << std::distance(start, end) << std::endl;
```

This snippet does not work, and for me it's perfectly clear why it does not: There is no possibility to follow one iterator until it reaches the other and count the steps.

But for me it's desirable to find out if two iterators point at the same iterable. The usecase is that I have lists and slices while slices have a start and an end pointing somewhere in the list. What I want to find out is if two slices share the same list. A workaround would be to provide my slices with a pointer to the list, of course, and then simply compare these pointers. But it was interesting to know if there is another way.

Comment: What's the use case for discovering if two slices share the same list?

Comment: @JeffreyYasskin, I want to merge consecutive slices. I could test start and end of the slices to be identical, but I want to implement a smarter algorithm.

Comment: In that case, it's likely to be more efficient to store the pointer to the list in the data structure that merges slices rather than in each slice.

Comment: How do you create slices? How do you store and pass slices around, such that there's a genuine possibility of not knowing (at compile time) which list a given slice belongs to? What are you going to do with the slices after merging them (i.e. why is it a problem to leave them unmerged)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, an explanation: I have "Ways" (lists of points) and want to perform a spatial search. Let's say I want to find all ways in a specific distance to a point. Therefore I slice the way in small slices and store those portions in a RTree. The query then gives me the slices and I want to merge them if they belong to the same way. I do not want to restore the whole way, just the section in my search window. I solved the problem by giving my slices a pointer to the way. Now, I can sort the slices first by way and then by position in the way and find consecutive ones.

Comment: Fair enough. BTW, we usually say "path" rather than "way" for this in English. That might help you with finding answers for other questions that come up for your project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302706/c-check-if-iterator-belongs-to-a-list) discusses a similar problem.

In short, comparing does not work, because the  C++03 standard is not perfectly clear about comparing iterators from different containers, and in C++11 it is explicitly forbidden.

A possible solution that works for standard containers is comparing the addresses of the contained elements.

Comment: Given that wal-o-mat has now said he wants to use this to merge adjacent slices, and some slices are likely to end with the non-dereferenceable past-the-end iterator, comparing addresses probably won't work. Otherwise, nice link.

Comment: I checked "accept" because you were the first to respond :) but what I keep in mind from this discussion is that I need to think about other ways to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

C++ iterators are designed to be very lightweight, so they generally don't contain a pointer back to their container. Instead, we either design algorithms to take ranges of iterators that the caller guarantees point into the same container, like `std::unique` or [`boost::sort`](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/sort.html), or we pass both the container and its iterators together, like `std::vector::erase`, again relying on the caller to keep track of which iterators point into which containers.