# How to find out whether iterator lies in a range?

Tags: c++, iterator

Suppose I have a container with three iterators, `it1`, `it2` and `it3`. Now I am using `it1` and `it2` to define a range, e.g. to pass to some std algorithm.

**How do I find out, whether `it3` lies within the range defined by `it1` and `it2`?**

I am aware of the brute force method of advancing a temporary iterator from `it1` to `it2` and checking against `it3` at each step. Is there a quicker way?

The preferred solution would be in standard C++, without libraries such as boost.

**edit:** It is not given apriori that `ìt3` acts on the same instance of a given container, for `it1` and `it2` that is always the case. So an additional qustion is: **Is there a way to find out that two iterators belong to the same instance of a container?**

Comment: Not all containers are created equal. Which ones did you have in mind? `vector`, `deque` and `list` should support this out of the box. `set` and `map` are ordered internally, but I don't know how much of that is exposed by their iterators. `unordered_map` and `unordered_set` iterators would not support this at all. I've no idea what `multiset` and `multimap` objects look like internally, but they may be ordered like their unique-membered cousins.

Comment: As regards your edit, that bit of functionality is an implementation detail of the specific iterators or containers. I think all the docs say is that comparing iterators from different containers is undefined... you might not even get an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Random access iterators are comparable. Just do `it1 < it3 && it2 > it3` - **if** they belong to the same collection.

You get random access iterators on collections that support O(1) indexing, such as `vector`,  `deque`, and `array`.

**edit**: Checking if an interator belongs to a given collection is not obviously feasible, and this should be a whole different question. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302706/c-check-if-iterator-belongs-to-a-list) for more details. (tl;dr: you can't.)

Comment: Wrong- this invokes UB if it3 is not from the same container.

Comment: @DeadMG: To be fair, the original wording of the question implied that they were from the same container. The question has changed since this answer was posted.

Answer (score 2):

For forward iterator:

- 1 scroll all of them to the end of the container and count offsets
- 2 compare offsets

For random access iterator compare them right away.

Answer (score 2):

There is no method that is efficient for all types of container, but a generic method would be to use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) and check its sign.

```
auto dist1 = std::distance(it1, it3); // should be 0 or +ve
auto dist2 = std::distance(it3, it2); // should be 0 or +ve
```

The only requirement is that the iterators satisfy `InputIterator` requirements.

Note that the behaviour is undefined if any of the iterators are not reachable from each other.

Comment: `distance` requires that the second iterator is reachable by advancing the first. The undefined behaviour might (accidentally) give a negative result for random-access iterators; but other iterator types would just advance off the end of the sequence into oblivion.

Comment: @juanchopanza: what would `std::distance` do if the iterators do not belong to the same container?

Comment: @steffen: It would give undefined behaviour; just as it would if `it3` were outside the range `[it1,it2]`.

Comment: @steffen undefined behaviour. I added a sentence explaining that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour actually, this solution is way too fragile. I think I will delete this post.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I don't think a negative result for random access iterators (or even bidirectional iterators) is an accident. It is what I would expect. Distance does return a signed integer after all.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Sorry, I should have checked the standard more carefully. This is well-defined for random-access iterators from the same sequence, but potentially undefined for other iterators.

Comment: So how do I check the iterators origins? Or is that a whole new question?

Comment: @steffen I think you can't. You have to be sure of it from the caller side.

Comment: This one is awful especially if the iterator being checked is not longer valid

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know where it came from, don't use the iterator. `<g>` Any comparisons you do are only valid if the iterator points into the range, so you can't use iterator comparisons to make that determination.

In most cases, though, you can use brute force:

```
while (first != last)
    if (&*first == &*questionable)
        // in sequence
```

that assumes that the iterator's value_type hasn't overloaded `operator&` in some funky way.