# unordered_multimap exact iterator validation method

Tags: c++, iterator, std, c++20

How would I check do iterator of different instance of map is not from map I wanted?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct test {
    test() {}
    void hello() {  std::cout << "hello"; }
};

void iter_pass(std::unordered_multimap< std::string, test >& myMap, std::unordered_multimap< std::string, test >::iterator& it) {

    if (it != myMap.end())
        it->second.hello();
    else
        std::cout << "error";
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_multimap< std::string, test > umap, umap2;
    std::unordered_multimap< std::string, test >::iterator it = umap.end();

    bool something(false);

    if (something)
        it = umap.emplace(std::make_pair(std::string("hello"), test()));
    else
        it = umap2.emplace(std::make_pair(std::string("hello"), test()));

    iter_pass(umap, it);
    return 0;
}
```

crushes at (incompatible list iterators), is there a way to safely check this?

Comment: Please include real code ([mcve]). Frankly, I find your pseudo code rather confusing

Comment: "something like getting reference to value "auto &obj = itr->second or auto && " provide object copy" no `obj` would be a reference to `itr->second` not a copy.

Comment: I thought that until non trivial copy constructor go to deal and inner std containers of myClass appears empty after someFunc

Comment: impossible to understand what you are talking about without a [mcve]

Comment: I'm asking how to create iterator instance and check whether is initialized (valid) or not unordered_multimap< string, class >::iterator it == ? map.end() ? but map end is not that it tobe meant.

Comment: `auto it = mymap.end();` is a valid iterator. If you later add elements to the map you can call `mymap.end()` again to get again a valid end iterator.

Comment: but it crashes as "incompatible list iterators". 
I think consider emplace method return single node iterator. 

Map work with special iterators (for equal_range) where it.first is beginning of range and it.last ending of range.
guess end provide pair of invalid iterator. so to check single iterator itself i need to use end().first but it's invalid :/

Comment: can only repeat: impossible to understand what you are talking about without a [mcve].

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Q4vedKKW

Comment: why do you not include that code in your question? I am really puzzled about that. The pseudo you posted here is neither shorter nor simpler to read

Comment: well i have hard time to make reproduction of crush, so after that offsource I reformulate question and paste code.

Comment: This Q&A is for a list, and it doesnt explain why it isnt directly possible, but the answer shows a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302706/check-whether-iterator-belongs-to-a-list In any case the TL;DR is: you cannot (directly) check if an iterator is from a given container or from a different one. You need to fix your design, why does `iter_pass` do the check and not the caller?

Comment: the problem in real code as figured for now: is that if iterator not instanciated how we can know is it will be belong to exact map later? offcourse iter_pass will be called with valid instance, but if not? workaround for me is to instanciate it to working instance of map.end or reinstanciate if map changes. but for me easier to check for is it instanciated at all. idea not to use additional flag bool it_valid(false); like if (something) it = emplace; it_valid = true; and then call pass_it if (it_valid == true) etc.